# Linux Kernel module OOM when memory is not full

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I write my own kernel module and I get this error:
Kernel panic - not syncing: Out of memory and no killable processes ...
But when I looking to htop I see the system use only 700 M from 3G. So they still have a memory.

I use customize linux kernel 2.6.32.61 and in this module I must often alloc 188 B. I use *kmem_cache_alloc()*, for alloc this memory. This error is strange, because is occurs randomly. Sometimes I got this error immediately, when I init the module and sometimes the module run some minutes. And sometimes I got this error: (see below).

Can you help me with this error?
Or can you give me more information about the error message(see below)?

On this error message I see function which I use, but when I look at it, it's look normal, so I don't know why I got this error.

Thanks for the help.

PS: Sorry for my bad English

```
sequencer_threa invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0xd0, order=0, oom_adj=0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043727] sequencer_threa cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043730] Pid: 2792, comm: sequencer_threa Not tainted 2.6.32.61 #18
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043731] Call Trace:
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043736]  [<c10919ce>] oom_kill_process+0x9e/0x2c0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043738]  [<c1091fcd>] ? select_bad_process+0xad/0xf0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043740]  [<c1092053>] __out_of_memory+0x43/0xb0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043742]  [<c1092332>] out_of_memory+0x52/0xb0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043744]  [<c109517c>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x55c/0x570
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043747]  [<c12c2387>] cache_alloc_refill+0x2ea/0x5f6
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043750]  [<c10b5ad6>] kmem_cache_alloc+0x136/0x150
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043753]  [<f9d94542>] ? alloc_ts_pkt+0x12/0x30 [optimux_rx]
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043756]  [<f9d94542>] alloc_ts_pkt+0x12/0x30 [optimux_rx]
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043758]  [<f9d9190c>] build_t2_mi_pkts+0x12c/0x360 [optimux_rx]
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043760]  [<c10b5a9d>] ? kmem_cache_alloc+0xfd/0x150
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043763]  [<f9d92f14>] parse_ref_packet+0x13d4/0x1e50 [optimux_rx]
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043765]  [<c12c6e02>] ? _spin_unlock_irq+0x22/0x30
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043768]  [<c105cbcb>] ? trace_hardirqs_on+0xb/0x10
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043770]  [<c1050eed>] ? sched_clock_cpu+0xed/0x160
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043773]  [<c1023af0>] ? finish_task_switch+0x0/0xd0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043776]  [<c11ca89b>] ? e1000e_set_d3_lplu_state+0x15b/0x170
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043778]  [<c12c6db1>] ? _spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x31/0x60
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043780]  [<c105cb54>] ? trace_hardirqs_on_caller+0x114/0x180
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043782]  [<c105cbcb>] ? trace_hardirqs_on+0xb/0x10
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043784]  [<f9d96ac9>] sequencer_thread+0x239/0x4a0 [optimux_rx]
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043787]  [<c104b450>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043790]  [<f9d96890>] ? sequencer_thread+0x0/0x4a0 [optimux_rx]
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043792]  [<c104aea5>] kthread+0x65/0x70
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043794]  [<c104ae40>] ? kthread+0x0/0x70
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043796]  [<c10038eb>] kernel_thread_helper+0x7/0x1c
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043797] Mem-Info:
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043798] DMA per-cpu:
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043799] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043800] CPU    1: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043801] CPU    2: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043802] CPU    3: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043803] Normal per-cpu:
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043804] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 144
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043805] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 197
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043806] CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 143
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043807] CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043808] HighMem per-cpu:
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043809] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 172
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043810] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 170
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043811] CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 169
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043812] CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043814] active_anon:4330 inactive_anon:1137 isolated_anon:0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043815]  active_file:1373 inactive_file:2388 isolated_file:0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043815]  unevictable:0 dirty:79 writeback:0 unstable:0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043816]  free:607286 slab_reclaimable:2764 slab_unreclaimable:190380
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043816]  mapped:1813 shmem:59 pagetables:160 bounce:0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043819] DMA free:3460kB min:64kB low:80kB high:96kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15668kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:11592kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043822] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 859 3236 3236
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043826] Normal free:2732kB min:3716kB low:4644kB high:5572kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:4kB inactive_file:68kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:879840kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:4kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:11056kB slab_unreclaimable:749928kB kernel_stack:952kB pagetables:640kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:28 all_unreclaimable? no
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043829] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 19015 19015
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043833] HighMem free:2422952kB min:512kB low:3080kB high:5652kB active_anon:17320kB inactive_anon:4548kB active_file:5488kB inactive_file:9484kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:2433944kB mlocked:0kB dirty:316kB writeback:0kB mapped:7248kB shmem:236kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043836] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043838] DMA: 2*4kB 2*8kB 1*16kB 2*32kB 2*64kB 3*128kB 1*256kB 1*512kB 0*1024kB 1*2048kB 0*4096kB = 3432kB
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043844] Normal: 16*4kB 1*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 1*64kB 1*128kB 0*256kB 1*512kB 0*1024kB 1*2048kB 0*4096kB = 2824kB
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043850] HighMem: 1485*4kB 808*8kB 471*16kB 204*32kB 99*64kB 36*128kB 5*256kB 1*512kB 2*1024kB 3*2048kB 580*4096kB = 2423076kB
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043855] 3815 total pagecache pages
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043856] 0 pages in swap cache
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043857] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043858] Free swap  = 1316856kB
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043859] Total swap = 1316856kB
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.048960] 849904 pages RAM
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.048961] 622594 pages HighMem
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.048962] 35058 pages reserved
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.048963] 8458 pages shared
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.048964] 202716 pages non-shared
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.048965] Out of memory: kill process 2797 (make) score 2343 or a child
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.049026] Killed process 2998 (beam.smp)
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094076] sequencer_threa invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0xd0, order=0, oom_adj=0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094080] sequencer_threa cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094082] Pid: 2792, comm: sequencer_threa Not tainted 2.6.32.61 #18
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094084] Call Trace:
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094088]  [<c10919ce>] oom_kill_process+0x9e/0x2c0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094090]  [<c1091fcd>] ? select_bad_process+0xad/0xf0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094092]  [<c1092053>] __out_of_memory+0x43/0xb0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094094]  [<c1092332>] out_of_memory+0x52/0xb0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094097]  [<c109517c>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x55c/0x570
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094100]  [<c12c2387>] cache_alloc_refill+0x2ea/0x5f6
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094103]  [<c10b5ad6>] kmem_cache_alloc+0x136/0x150
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094107]  [<f9d94542>] ? alloc_ts_pkt+0x12/0x30 [optimux_rx]
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094109]  [<f9d94542>] alloc_ts_pkt+0x12/0x30 [optimux_rx]
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094111]  [<f9d92b04>] parse_ref_packet+0xfc4/0x1e50 [optimux_rx]
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094114]  [<c105a89b>] ? trace_hardirqs_off+0xb/0x10
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094116]  [<c1050f05>] ? sched_clock_cpu+0x105/0x160
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094119]  [<c1050eed>] ? sched_clock_cpu+0xed/0x160
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094121]  [<c10b45e3>] ? cache_free_debugcheck+0xe3/0x300
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094124]  [<c113d465>] ? __debug_check_no_obj_freed+0x125/0x190
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094125]  [<c105a89b>] ? trace_hardirqs_off+0xb/0x10
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094128]  [<c105cbcb>] ? trace_hardirqs_on+0xb/0x10
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094130]  [<f9d969da>] sequencer_thread+0x14a/0x4a0 [optimux_rx]
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094134]  [<c104b450>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094136]  [<f9d96890>] ? sequencer_thread+0x0/0x4a0 [optimux_rx]
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094139]  [<c104aea5>] kthread+0x65/0x70
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094141]  [<c104ae40>] ? kthread+0x0/0x70
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094143]  [<c10038eb>] kernel_thread_helper+0x7/0x1c
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094144] Mem-Info:
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094145] DMA per-cpu:
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094146] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094147] CPU    1: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094148] CPU    2: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094149] CPU    3: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094150] Normal per-cpu:
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094152] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 165
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094153] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 204
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094154] CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 143
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094155] CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  33
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094156] HighMem per-cpu:
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094156] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 172
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094157] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 170
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094158] CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 169
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094160] CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 116
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094162] active_anon:4329 inactive_anon:1041 isolated_anon:0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094163]  active_file:1394 inactive_file:2381 isolated_file:0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094163]  unevictable:0 dirty:92 writeback:0 unstable:0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094164]  free:607290 slab_reclaimable:2518 slab_unreclaimable:190594
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094165]  mapped:1744 shmem:59 pagetables:155 bounce:0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094168] DMA free:3460kB min:64kB low:80kB high:96kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15668kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:11592kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094171] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 859 3236 3236
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094175] Normal free:2872kB min:3716kB low:4644kB high:5572kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:4kB inactive_file:68kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:879840kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:4kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:10072kB slab_unreclaimable:750784kB kernel_stack:952kB pagetables:620kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094179] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 19015 19015
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094183] HighMem free:2422828kB min:512kB low:3080kB high:5652kB active_anon:17316kB inactive_anon:4164kB active_file:5572kB inactive_file:9456kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:2433944kB mlocked:0kB dirty:368kB writeback:0kB mapped:6972kB shmem:236kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094186] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094188] DMA: 2*4kB 2*8kB 1*16kB 2*32kB 2*64kB 3*128kB 1*256kB 1*512kB 0*1024kB 1*2048kB 0*4096kB = 3432kB
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094194] Normal: 28*4kB 1*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 1*64kB 1*128kB 0*256kB 1*512kB 0*1024kB 1*2048kB 0*4096kB = 2872kB
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094200] HighMem: 1454*4kB 808*8kB 471*16kB 204*32kB 99*64kB 36*128kB 5*256kB 1*512kB 2*1024kB 3*2048kB 580*4096kB = 2422952kB
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094206] 3790 total pagecache pages
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094207] 0 pages in swap cache
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094208] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094209] Free swap  = 1316856kB
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.094209] Total swap = 1316856kB
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.099045] 849904 pages RAM
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.099046] 622594 pages HighMem
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.099047] 35058 pages reserved
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.099048] 8161 pages shared
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.099048] 202610 pages non-shared
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.099050] Out of memory: kill process 2459 (dbus-daemon) score 743 or a child
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.099114] Killed process 2459 (dbus-daemon)
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112749] htop invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x800d0, order=0, oom_adj=0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112753] htop cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112755] Pid: 3074, comm: htop Not tainted 2.6.32.61 #18
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112756] Call Trace:
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112761]  [<c10919ce>] oom_kill_process+0x9e/0x2c0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112764]  [<c1091fcd>] ? select_bad_process+0xad/0xf0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112766]  [<c1092053>] __out_of_memory+0x43/0xb0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112768]  [<c1092332>] out_of_memory+0x52/0xb0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112770]  [<c109517c>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x55c/0x570
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112773]  [<c1101430>] ? proc_info_read+0x0/0xc0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112776]  [<c10951a7>] __get_free_pages+0x17/0x30
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112778]  [<c110146b>] proc_info_read+0x3b/0xc0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112780]  [<c1101430>] ? proc_info_read+0x0/0xc0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112783]  [<c10bfa34>] vfs_read+0x84/0x180
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112785]  [<c1101430>] ? proc_info_read+0x0/0xc0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112787]  [<c10bfb68>] sys_read+0x38/0x70
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112789]  [<c1002cd4>] sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x32
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112790] Mem-Info:
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112791] DMA per-cpu:
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112792] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112794] CPU    1: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112795] CPU    2: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112796] CPU    3: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112797] Normal per-cpu:
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112798] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  53
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112800] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 175
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112801] CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 160
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112802] CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  57
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112803] HighMem per-cpu:
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112804] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 172
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112805] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 170
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112806] CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 157
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112807] CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 113
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112810] active_anon:4201 inactive_anon:1114 isolated_anon:0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112811]  active_file:1394 inactive_file:2326 isolated_file:0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112811]  unevictable:0 dirty:92 writeback:0 unstable:0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112812]  free:607509 slab_reclaimable:2518 slab_unreclaimable:190569
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112813]  mapped:1744 shmem:59 pagetables:155 bounce:0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112816] DMA free:3460kB min:64kB low:80kB high:96kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15668kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:11592kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112819] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 859 3236 3236
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112824] Normal free:3500kB min:3716kB low:4644kB high:5572kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:4kB inactive_file:68kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:879840kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:4kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:10072kB slab_unreclaimable:750784kB kernel_stack:952kB pagetables:620kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112828] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 19015 19015
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112832] HighMem free:2423076kB min:512kB low:3080kB high:5652kB active_anon:16804kB inactive_anon:4456kB active_file:5572kB inactive_file:9236kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:2433944kB mlocked:0kB dirty:368kB writeback:0kB mapped:6972kB shmem:236kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:96 all_unreclaimable? no
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112836] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112838] DMA: 2*4kB 2*8kB 1*16kB 2*32kB 2*64kB 3*128kB 1*256kB 1*512kB 0*1024kB 1*2048kB 0*4096kB = 3432kB
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112844] Normal: 161*4kB 12*8kB 1*16kB 0*32kB 1*64kB 1*128kB 0*256kB 1*512kB 0*1024kB 1*2048kB 0*4096kB = 3508kB
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112850] HighMem: 1440*4kB 802*8kB 471*16kB 211*32kB 101*64kB 36*128kB 5*256kB 1*512kB 2*1024kB 3*2048kB 580*4096kB = 2423200kB
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112856] 3790 total pagecache pages
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112857] 0 pages in swap cache
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112858] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112859] Free swap  = 1316856kB
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.112860] Total swap = 1316856kB
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.117742] 849904 pages RAM
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.117743] 622594 pages HighMem
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.117744] 35058 pages reserved
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.117745] 8060 pages shared
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.117746] 202704 pages non-shared
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.117748] Out of memory: kill process 1897 (rpc.statd) score 601 or a child
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.117808] Killed process 1897 (rpc.statd)
```

Comment: Im pretty sure kernel memory allocation is always contiguous. So when you get an out of memory error you may simply not have a large enough contiguous block of memory to allocate.

Comment: http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?kmem_cache_alloc+9

Comment: OOM is usually triggered because (1) no more pages are available in the backing store (e.g. swap), and/or (2) no more virtual address space is available (this condition is usually handled gracefully).  You need to determine which one of these two causes is happening.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons you could be hitting a out-of-memory issues, first and foremost being lack of availability of sufficiently large contiguous memory being request by kmem_cache_create(). Note that kmem_cache_create() uses the SLAB layer as I suspect from the output provided.

From the `dmesg` output seems to be missing the a line followed by a table similar to the below, this table should give more information about the processes causing the OOM error along with oom_adj score and the resident memory used by the process. Higher the oom_adj_score, more likely the process is going to get killed.

```
kernel: [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss cpu oom_adj oom_score_adj name
```

Try the following command instead to get more information in the `dmesg` output:
    dmesg -l info,notice,warn,err,crit,alert,emerg

Additionally you may also want to consider setting the following in /etc/sysctl.conf file and running `sysctl -p` (to avoid restart):

```
vm.overcommit_memory = 2
vm.overcommit_ratio = 80
```

Refer to this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103792/how-do-i-read-the-output-of-dmesg-to-determine-how-much-memory-a-process-is-us)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the system is running 32 bit kernel which may run out of virtual memory addresses even if free RAM is available. 32 bit kernels can effectively handle up to around 2 GB of real RAM without "interesting" limitations.

The kernel log line that's interesting here looks like this:

```
Sep 25 14:20:51 optisat kernel: [  159.043826] Normal free:2732kB min:3716kB low:4644kB high:5572kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:4kB inactive_file:68kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:879840kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:4kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:11056kB slab_unreclaimable:749928kB kernel_stack:952kB pagetables:640kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:28 all_unreclaimable? no
```

Note the part `Normal free:2732kB min:3716kB` which says that normal memory zone (the part that fits in 32 bit addressing space) is below the minimum which will stop all user processes that try to request more RAM until some can be freed. So your normal memory zone only has 2.7 MB free when the high memory zone still has 2.4 GB free.

The only real way to fix the problem is to upgrade to 64 bit OS but tweaking the system to reduce "normal" memory zone usage might help, too. For example, some people have noticed that disabling network adapter hardware acceleration could reduce normal memory zone usage quite a bit.

Using user mode programs that avoid `mmap()` and other functions that require big block of virtual memory addresses might help, too. However, because `mmap()` is not a problem with 64 bit OS and using it usually improves runtime performance, most modern applications actually prefer using `mmap()` for everything. And that makes using 32 bit OS worse idea with modern OS and applications.

Also note that some security features (e.g. KASRL) require bigger address spaces than 32 bit to be effectively implemented so using a 32 bit OS also reduces security of your system.

TL;DR: If you need to handle *any* files bigger than 2 GB or have more than 2 GB of RAM installed on your system, you should be running 64 bit OS.